# How do you assign variables of a base type to one of an extended type in fortran with GNU?

Tags: fortran, gnu, gfortran, intel-fortran

I have a module where I define two types, where one extends the other. In this particular case, I first define a variable of the base-type and then convert it to the extended type to assign it to a variable that is defined as such:

```
module my_test_module

  type :: baseType
  end type baseType

  type, extends(baseType) :: extendedType
  end type extendedType

end module my_test_module

Program TEST
  use my_test_module
  implicit none

  class(baseType), pointer :: &
    generic_var
  type(extendedType) :: &
    extended_var

  allocate(extendedType::generic_var)
  select type(generic_var)
    class is (extendedType)
      extended_var = generic_var
      print *, "ran successfully"
  end select
End Program TEST
```

This works, but since I would like to do assertions such as `extended_var = generic_var` more frequently, I would like to be able to assign variables of type `baseType` to variables of type `extendedType` without performing the select class confirmation every time. For this purpose, I implemented a type procedure that looks as following:

```
module my_test_module

  type :: baseType
    contains
    procedure :: &
      asExtended       => baseType_asExtended
  end type baseType

  type, extends(baseType) :: extendedType
  end type extendedType
  contains

  function baseType_asExtended(self) result(extended)
    class(baseType), intent(in), target :: self
    class(extendedType), pointer        :: extended

    select type(self)
      class is (extendedType)
        extended => self
      class default
        print *, "invalid base class type"
        STOP
    end select
  end function baseType_asExtended

end module my_test_module

Program TEST
  use my_test_module
  implicit none

  class(baseType),    pointer :: &
    generic_var
  type(extendedType) :: &
    extended_var

  allocate(extendedType::generic_var) ! compiler error happens without this line as well
  extended_var = generic_var%asExtended()
  print *, "ran successfully"
End Program TEST
```

However, this results in an internal compiler error on gfortran GNU 10.3.0:

```
   38 |   extended_object = generic_object%asExtended()
      |                                               1
internal compiler error: in conv_function_val, at fortran/trans-expr.c:4158
```

The same code has no problems compiling on intel’s ifort 2021.6.0 20220226. How can I reformulate the `baseType_asExtended` function to allow me to assign the `extended_var` variable as `extended_var = generic_var%asExtended()`?

Comment: **Internal** compiler error means that there is a bug in the compiler. Submit a bug report to GCC as mentioned in theberror message. Test a more recent version of the compiler, it may have been fixed in later versions.

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава I know and I already did, but I wanted to know if there is a good way to implement a workaround since it's likely that this issue won't be fixed in the near future.

Comment: Searching for a workaround is always trial and error. But someone may be able to find something. But it often takes a lot of time. But I do not actually see why such a function would be necessary in the first place.

Comment: So you think the select `type(self) -> class is (extendedType)` solution is already good enough in most cases?

Comment: It shows the intent and it is quite clear why such a thing needs a typeguard.